# Joomla call another controller function

Tags: php, joomla, visibility

hi currently i have 2 controllers as follow:

item.php

```
function convertItem(){

}
```

project.php

```
function saveProject(){

}
```

How can i call saveProject() function within convertItem() ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

in item.php you first include the definitions from `project.php` and then call it.

```
require_once "project.php";
saveProject();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create object of that controller and call the function with the help of object.

Like

```
$obj = new className();
$obj->saveProject();
```